# Como separar dados que estão na mesma coluna no Rstudio?

Tags: microsoft-excel, r, dplyr, data.rable-r

Boa noite, tenho uma tabela que importei do excel para o RStudio e eu quero trabalhar com a coluna "Date". Preciso separar a data das horas e até agora não obtive sucesso através do data.table, meu objetivo é criar uma coluna para "hora" e uma coluna para "data". Quem puder ajudar, agradeço!
[image: tabela tem duas colunas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que esse separador entre data e hora seja o espaço, você pode fazer assim:

Exemplo reproduzível:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(value = c("10", "20"), 
            Date = c("2021-10-01 03:15", "2021-10-01    00:20"))
```

Função:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_1 %>% 
  separate(data = ., col = Date, 
       into = c("nova_data", "hora"), sep = "[[:space:]]+")

#   value  nova_data  hora
#1     10 2021-10-01 03:15
#2     20 2021-10-01 00:20
```